# Is it possible to have two files in the src folder in PlatformIO (Atom)?

Tags: c++, arduino, atom-editor, file-structure, platformio

When I create two code files in the `src` folder on PlatformIO (microcontroller plugin for Atom), I get an error when building and uploading to my Arduino. Is there a way to do this without the error?

I have looked at a tutorial online by Robin Reiter and it suggests you can do this.

[image: "PlatformIO - A Great Arduino IDE Alternative" - youtube scrn shot]

When I try this I get an error. The program runs fine when I have just one file in the `src` folder.

> Error: *** [.pioenvs/uno/src/flashLed2.ino.o] Error 1

[image: Atom with Platformio installed]

NB: this was a project file imported from an Arduino IDE project (the `.ino`) but also happens if I create the project, use the `.cpp` extension and paste the code into the text file.

How can I create multiple files in one project?

Answer (score 3):

If you are importing project from Arduino then rename the main file to main.cpp first. Use extern and function name from the file. Refer given example. Suppose you have two files viz main.cpp and someFuntion.cpp and you want to call functions from someFunction.cpp in main.cpp then,

someFunction.cpp

```
void someFunction() {
    int i = 0;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
extern void someFunction();
void setup() {
}
void loop() {
    someFunction();
}
```

Comment: With this method, you can access variables from other files too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's you need a main file to be compiled by platformio. If this other files are imported from main file, then they're libs.

Is it really necessary that files stay in /src? Try to put your files into /lib folder like.

```
- /lib
  - /myLib
     - myLib.h
     - myLib.cpp
```